# Use XML Data exported from Health App

Tags: ms-office, xml

I'm trying to write some code to import in Excel the xml export from the health app Excel so I can chart various metrics over a longer period with more detail. For the blood glucose readings, the "startDate" and "endDate" attributes don't appear to be dates connected to times the data was entred using the app on the iPhone.

Anyone have an idea on how to interpret these dates?  It is an average of some type?  I can't find any documentation on the xml entries.

One thing to note - for the "weight" xml entries, the time in the xml export is the exact time the entry was added to the iPhone app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The timestamps use ISO 8601, so the time of the first record is 6:43-7:43am (PDT), and the second record is 5:43-6:43pm (PDT). Looks like the Health app exports values aggregated at the hour level, not individual measurements, though it seems strange that the times don't start at full hours.

Does the Health app have any options for the export? Couldn't find any documentation, either, and would love to get hold of a sample file (I don't have an iOS device at the moment)!